# PowerShell hashtable filtering values in array

Tags: powershell, hashtable

File : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GAlcA9PI-mFHUmACvC5CPbzjl3QLrwJ/view?usp=sharing

```
$data = import-csv .\vDisk.csv |where 'raw lun id' -NotLike ''|Group-Object -Property VM -ashashtable
```

I have vdisk extracted from rvtools and trying to group shared RDM by VM name, the output of the code is:

```text
Name                           Value
----                           -----
MGTMKS1112M                    {@{VM=MGTMKS1112M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 7; Capacity MB=150; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; Wri...
PRDSKM1111M                    {@{VM=PRDSKM1111M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 5; Capacity MB=1,024; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; W...
MGTMKS1111M                    {@{VM=MGTMKS1111M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 11; Capacity MB=150; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; Wr...
PRDSKM1112M                    {@{VM=PRDSKM1112M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 5; Capacity MB=1,024; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; W...
```

I want the the output like below ashashtable or grouped object. because two nodes share the same raw lun ids. if this approach cant work. any alternate methods? please advice.

```text
Name                      Value
----                      -----
MGTMKS1112M,MGTMKS1111M   {@{VM=MGTMKS1112M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 7; Capacity MB=150; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; Wri...
PRDSKM1112M,PRDSKM1112M   {@{VM=PRDSKM1112M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 5; Capacity MB=1,024; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; W...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may provide a custom property to Group-Object in which to group on

```
$data = import-csv .\vDisk.csv |where 'raw lun id' -NotLike ''
$data | Group-Object -Property { $sub = $_.vm.substring(0,9); ($data.vm -match $sub |  Select-Object -Unique | Sort-Object) -join ", "} -ashashtable
```

Output something like this

```
    Name                     Value
----                     -----
MGTMKS1111M, MGTMKS1112M {@{VM=MGTMKS1111M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 11; Capacity MB=150; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; Write Through=; Level=normal; Shares=1,000; Reservation=0; L...
PRDSKM1111M, PRDSKM1112M {@{VM=PRDSKM1111M; Powerstate=poweredOff; Template=False; Disk=Hard disk 5; Capacity MB=1,024; Raw=True; Disk Mode=independent_persistent; Thin=; Eagerly Scrub=; Split=; Write Through=; Level=normal; Shares=1,000; Reservation=0; ...
```

Comment: The name got trimmed because of substring (0..9). any other way i can have the duplicate reference name? Ex: MGTMKS1112M as duplicate ref for MGTMKS1111M. otherwise both in comma separated as single string. also i will need to enumerate the values later in function.

Comment: any other way, i can filter by VM and compare its values? main key is Raw lun mapping matching to VM name.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Try that.

Comment: the above code output is different than your output is shown. can help to check.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have access to your csv file before.  Updated once more to remove the duplicates by adding `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: Possible to collect the values of ‘raw lun id’ and match against each vms ‘raw lun I’d ’ . In this case we can avoid different name of vms having the same ‘raw lun id’  . Ex VM’s ABC raw lun id matching VM’s DEF raw lun id.

Comment: Primary goal is group of lun ids in a vm matching against any VM’s lun id. Thanks a lot for the response and almost close the solution

Comment: So now that I have the csv I see that Raw LUN ID is a column in the file.  Why do you not just group by that property?  `Group-Object "Raw LUN ID" `  Why are you grouping by VM?

Comment: i have a function to attach raw lun ids for the given vms. the function param is [array]vms,lunids. hence i would like to follow pass set of vms for a set of lunids in one go. if filter through raw lun ids. its difficult to attach with ctrls..etc.